# ZFS, NFS and user based quotas

Tags: nfs, zfs

I am using a ZFS storage (FreeNAS 9.1) with NFSv3. The NFS is mounted on Debian machine, where the linux users are created (they don`t exists on FreeNAS). How do I enable standard linux user based quotas? I want to get/set quotas on Debian, FreeNAS should make the accounting.

Is this even possible?

Will the NFSv4 help for this? If yes how can I mount an NFSv4 share without having the same linux users on FreeNAS.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

On FreeNas you can set the per user quota @ the ZFS level.

Something like this should do it:
**zfs set userquota@someuser=100g tank**

but this will require you having local users on the FreeNAS box.

The other alternative is to create a dataset per user and set the quotas on the dataset.
There are some good advantages to having per user datasets. Quotas,snapshots and replication come to mind.

NFSv4 is not supported on FreeNAS 9.1